# How to subtract months from a date field

Tags: formula, formula-field, report-formula

How to subtract months from a date field:

I have a date field on opportunity, called: Current Term End date.
I want to create a Formula field, which will subtract 3 month from Current Term End date and display result in numbers.

```
Current Term End date - 3 month = days left.
```

Basically i am displaying, how many days left for that opportunity to close/update something like this.

Comment: are you considering today's date also for this calculation?

Comment: Put your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I tried like this. Get the date 3 month before current term end date by this : Current_Term_End_Date__c -((365/12) * 3). Then to calculate Number of days left (Formula field)= (Current_Term_End_Date__c) - (Current_Term_End_Date__c -((365/12) * 3)).

Comment: edit your question and put this

Answer (score 2):

With formula fields, date artithemetic is done in days.

Example: `MyDateField__c - 5` substracts 5 days.

To substract a conceptual month you could do `MyDateField__c - 30` to subtract 30 days.

However, not every month is **exactly** 30 days, so if you need very accurate result you will need to consider either:

(a) complicated formula, or

(b) rely on apex to do the date calculation for you, such as in a trigger or have process builder call an invocable apex class whenever the record or field value changes.

## Formula Functions

For reference, please see these documentation articles about date/time functions in formula fields:

- [Using Date and Date/Time Values in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=0)
- [Formula Operations and Functions A-H](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US)
- [Sample Date Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

## Apex Methods

- [Date Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)